# summarise with dplyr group by function ignores factor

Tags: r, dplyr

The summarise function in dplyr by means the group by function returns a single value, even though the group by is filled with a factor. What is wrong here?

```
cols <- c("GGEES203","cl_kmeans")
y <- y[which(y$cl_kmeans>0),cols]
y$cl_kmeans <- as.factor(y$cl_kmeans)
str(y)
    'data.frame':   3863 obs. of  2 variables:
     $ GGEES203 : num  4 11 3 0 9 0 10 11 8 10 ...
     $ cl_kmeans: Factor w/ 9 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 6 4 3 3 6 6 4 9 9 5 ...
gd <- y %>% 
group_by(cl_kmeans) %>% 
summarise(eenzaamheid_avg = mean(GGEES203, na.rm = TRUE))


      eenzaamheid_avg
    1            7.29
    >
```

Comment: can u try with as.character instead of factor

Comment: output is still the same

Comment: Can you try using `group_by(cl_kmeans)`? No need to use `$` with `dplyr`.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: Can you post the `y` dataset using `dput`? I need to make sure I can replicate that issue.

Comment: Hmmm. I think I got it. Which packages are you using? Very likely you're using `plyr` which will break your grouping. Try to do the same using ONLY `dplyr`. If you really need to use both do first `library(plyr)` and then `library(dplyr)`.

Comment: yes may be...dont run the dplyr before run of plyr

Comment: you are right AntoniosK, thank you very much